# Missing wsrep variables in mysql / percona / galera cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, percona, galera

I set up a small mysql/percona/galera cluster using the percona cluster docker image, with 3 nodes.

I followed the documentation written [here](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/LATEST/install/docker.html)

After starting up the whole cluster, I'm missing some of the wsrep variables.

For instance *wsrep_local_state_comment*. (among many others)

Does anyone knows why is this happening ?

(I'd imagine it is not, strictly ,percona related, but I don't know)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After starting up the whole cluster, I'm missing some of the wsrep variables.

I'm not sure if this is the issue, but 
`wsrep_local_state_comment` is not a wsrep variable, it's a status variable. Which means you have to use `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE ...` rather than `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE ...`, i.e. in this case:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_local_state_comment';
```

And more generally:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep%';
```

Comment: You should probably do `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep%';` for the heck of it.